# A weird case in if statement in Visual Basic.Net

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

[image: A weird case in if clause in Visual Basic]

Here I'am checking if
***WebBrowserEx1.Document.All.Item(t).OuterHtml***  is equal to ***abc*** but despite that they are same, it doesnt accept them same and does not perform the code in if statement. The blind one is me or Visual Basic ?

Big Pic : https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVjpH.png

Edit:

```
For t = 1 To WebBrowserEx1.Document.All.Count
    Dim abc = "<LI style=""PADDING-BOTTOM: 2px; PADDING-TOP: 2px"">Hata oluştu. İşlem tamamlanamamıştır. "
    If WebBrowserEx1.Document.All.Item(t).OuterHtml = abc Then
                        WebBrowserEx1.Navigate("http://uyg.sgk.gov.tr/vizite/tarihGiris.do")
       loc = "giris"
       WebBrowserEx1.Update()
       yeniSayfa = True

       Exit For
     End If
Next
```

Value of WebBrowserEx1.Document.All.Item(t).OuterHtml in watch:
"Hata oluştu. İşlem tamamlanamamıştır. "

The Value of abc in watch:
"Hata oluştu. İşlem tamamlanamamıştır. "

I think big pic should be more explanatory.

Second try with type correction

```
For t = 1 To WebBrowserEx1.Document.All.Count
                    Dim abc As String
                    abc = "<LI style=""PADDING-BOTTOM: 2px; PADDING-TOP: 2px"">Hata oluştu. İşlem tamamlanamamıştır. "
                    If WebBrowserEx1.Document.All.Item(t).OuterHtml = abc Then
                        WebBrowserEx1.Navigate("http://uyg.sgk.gov.tr/vizite/tarihGiris.do")
                        loc = "giris"
                        WebBrowserEx1.Update()
                        yeniSayfa = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
```

Comment: A screen shot of code? Why not post the code as text, so people can copy/paste and try it out?

Comment: The text is in that image is so small it's almost impossible to read. You won't get much help if you we can't read your code. Please actually paste the text of your code and the text of the error, and use the markdown code formatting feature.

Comment: Also, we need the exact html loaded into the webbrowser control.

Comment: Have you tried .Trim() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note the type of each object in the right column.** Since abc variable is of type "Object", the `=` operator is checking for *reference* equality. The object referred to by abc may be a string, but since the variable is merely typed as an Object, you get the reference comparison. Since those two objects do not refer to the same block of memory, the compare returns `False`. Change your `abc` declaration to look like this:

```
Dim abc As String = "<LI ... "
```

Some other things to look for:

- Any whitespace difference won't show up in the debug/watch windows, which can mangle the displayed value of your variables to fit in the space. Try clicking on the magnifying glass for a closer look.
- I see some non-ascii characters. Make sure you're using the exact same unicode code points, or the comparison can fail.

Comment: I thought the same and changed the code, but nothing changed.

Comment: Yeah in magnifying glass I see that there is a newline in the beginning of the outerHtml but not sure how to handle it ?

Comment: @Mtok you could trim the whitespace, or Chr(10)/Chr(13) to help build the string you need for the match.

Comment: "Since `abc` variable is of type `Object`, the `=`operator is checking for reference equality." Nope, the `=` operator in this case is compiled to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Operators.CompareObjectEqual` where (via `CompareObject2`) it applies the same comparisons at runtime that the two real types would at compile time, in this case `String` equality (via `CompareString`).

Answer (score 1):

Test the `Len()` of the two strings. If they're different, there's some whitespace issues.

Otherwise (or in any case to find out where the differences start) check character-by-character until you find a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Try to normalize the strings. They might look the same but have a different Unicode representation

```
If WebBrowserEx1.Document.All.Item(t).OuterHtml.Normalize() = abc.Normalize() Then
    ...
End If
```

(And type `abc` as `String` as other have pointed out already. It seems that the VB type inference is not as good as C# type inference.)

Answer (score -1):

Try casting `abc` as a `String`.

`dim abc as string`

or ...

`OuterHTML = cstr(abc)`

I guess the problems lies in comparing `Object` to `String`.